# header for base64 POST request

Tags: node.js, post, cors, base64

In my Angular project, I take a screenshot that I get in base64 format in order to send it with a `POST` request.
Everything works but, when I put it in production mode, I have a CORS error.

I think it's linked because a base64 is a long string
I tried header:
`Content-type: application/octet-stream`,
`Content-type: application/json`.

CORS error:

[image: error]

CORS config:

```
app.use(cors());

app.use((req, res, next) => {

res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'),

  res.header(

    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
    'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization',);

    if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
         res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE, GET');
         return res.status(200).json({});
     }
next();
});
```

Angular request :

```
headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' };


  generateSignature(signature) {
    const data = {signature:signature}
    return this.http
    .post(this.url + 'generateSignature',JSON.stringify(data) , { headers: this.headers} )
    .toPromise()
    .then(res => res as any);
  }
```

Comment: *in production mode I have a CORS error*. What is the error in question? This is crucial information for people here to be able to help you...

Comment: Note that you never need to specify `Origin` in the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` response header. Also, `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` is a response header for the preflight request, not for the actual request.

Comment: Finally, please post the actual source code of your CORS config rather than a picture. It will be easier for people here to play with.

Answer (score 0):

The `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` header should be specified in the response to the preflight request, but in your code, you're setting it in the response to the actual request.

Also, you're both using Express's CORS middleware *and* setting CORS headers "manually". There's no need for that. Just configure the middleware properly:

```js
const options = {
    origin: 'http://localhost:4200',
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
    methods: ['PUT', 'POST', 'PATCH', 'DELETE', 'GET'],
    allowHeaders: ['X-Requested-With', 'Content-Type', 'Accept', 'Authorization']
};

app.use(cors(options));
```

Finally, there's never a need to list `Origin` in the allowed headers, because that request header is automatically set by the browser itself and [therefore gets a pass](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#simple_requests).